# Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle - redirection not working in controller

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have my default controller with the route "`/`" set to run index:

```
public function indexAction() {
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        //render the logged in view(s)
        $response = $this->render('Pan100MoodLogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    } else {
        //redirect to the login controller
        $response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

But Symfony cannot find the route:

> Route "login" does not exist.
>   500 Internal Server Error - RouteNotFoundException

What can be wrong? I am using FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to `fos_user_security_login`

```
$response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you type

```
php app/console router:debug
```

you will see all your application routes.

With `php app/console router:debug | grep login`, it shows:

```
fos_user_security_login               ANY      /login
fos_user_security_check               ANY      /login_check
```

So try

```
$response = $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you don't have a route with the name 'login'.
You have to create it in your route.yml|xml file, but you don't have to specify the controller, cause FOS will handle it, like this in the yml:

```
login:
    pattern: /login
```

EDIT:
Sorry, my mistake, not layout of course, login.
But are you shore, the route is loaded? Cause generateUrl expect a route name.

Comment: I placed this in my config/routing and it did not work. It works the way I described in my answer, but I don't know if it is the correct thing to do...